# Using и картинка в MemoryStream'е

Tags: .net, winforms, vb.net

Почему этот код работает

```vb
Dim PctStream As MemoryStream = Await GetSomePct()
Me.BackgroundImage = Bitmap.FromStream(PctStream)
```

а этот - нет?

```vb
Using PctStream As MemoryStream = Await GetSomePct()
  Me.BackgroundImage = Bitmap.FromStream(PctStream)
End Using
```

В случае с `Using` вместо картинки отображается перечёркнутый прямоугольник.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы закрываете `stream`, к которому при отрисовке обращается GDI+.

На [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/93z9ee4x.aspx) есть заметка:

> Необходимо сохранять поток открытым в течение времени существования
>   Image

Comment: Странно, подобная конструкция с FileStream, но без await у меня успешно работает

Comment: @3per, т.е. using(FileStream fs = new FileStream("путь к картинке", FileMode.Open)) BackgroundImage = Bitmap.FromStream(fs); отработает без Exception?
Или на vb:
Using fs As New FileStream("путь к картинке", FileMode.Open)
    BackgroundImage = Bitmap.FromStream(fs)
End Using

Comment: Да ваш код вызывает исключение, причём исключение происходит не при установке значения свойства, оно проходит нормально, а после, видимо когда происходит отрисовка формы.

Comment: @3per, а у Вас в каком случае работало успешно?

Comment: PictureBox кидаем на форму   using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\2.jpg", FileMode.Open)) pictureBox1.Image = Bitmap.FromStream(fs);

Comment: Как-то нелогично...

Comment: @Qwertiy, нелогично, что для picturebox работает, а для формы такое не проходит? PictureBox, у себя использует объект graphics, и как я понял, в этом нативном методе http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Graphics.cs,2768 обращение к image идет без повторного декодирования. Не знаю, что там происходит, но к stream'у-источнику обращений нет.
А вот при отрисовке формы http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Advanced/TextureBrush.cs,83 уже идет обращение к начальному потоку. NativeCode -> GPStream -> dataStream (исходный)

Comment: @Qwertiy, может здесь найдутся спецы по GDI+, и объяснят, как и где, и почему так работает. А пока нужно принять за данность: нельзя освобождать поток, если картинка где-то будет использоваться

Comment: @nuts119, а как быть мне, если файл необходимо закрыть?